# How do I join 2 columns from 2 different tabels?

Tags: php, mysql

First of all, thanks for helping me!
I am new at this and i'm stuck at 'this' point..

I have 2 tabels **blog_memebers** and **blog_post**.
In **blog_members** I have a column named **memberID** and
in **blog_post** I have a column named **postUser**.

I want to couple the **memberID** to the **postUser** (*these should be the same*).

The problem now is that if i post something under the name Demo I get the same post also under the name Test (*thats why i need a **postUser** or **memberID** with it, so it's linkt to just one user and NOT all of them*)

In the end I want to see a blog post with username, title and date (*from the right User, who had posted it*).

(*I'm using MySQL of course*)

Can you guys please help 0:)

I thank you for your time and hope you have a nice day!

Comment: share your codes so we can help to correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 'Demo' and 'Test' are the blog posts names then:

```html
SELECT blog_post.title, blog_post.date, blog_members.username FROM blog_post JOIN blog_members ON blog_post.postUser = blog_members.memberID WHERE blog_post.title = 'Demo';
```

This should return only one result provided that there are no more posts with the title of 'Demo';

if 'Demmo' and 'Test' are the user names then:

```html
SELECT blog_post.title, blog_post.date, blog_members.username FROM blog_post JOIN blog_members ON blog_post.postUser = blog_members.memberID WHERE blog_members.username = 'Demo';
```

This will return more results if the user 'Demo' made more than one posts.

Comment: Only the user you need (second query). You can add more conditions to the WHERE clause like the post title.

Comment: Thank again I go try this one out! Let's see if i get this.. ;P

Comment: IT WORKS!! (I only had to put in a FROM and it's working!) THANKS!

Comment: sorry for that one, I have added the missing FROM just in case somebody else will be looking at it, glad I could help ;)